# Paragon NTFS app version problem, how to update?

Tags: macos, ntfs

I have a little problem (not me, a friend).

He bought a 1TB HDD with some service files, including Paragon NTFS 11.3.11 (he bought this HDD with his Mac, which shipped with Mac OS X version 10.10 or 10.11). He has updated his MacBook to 10.12 and Paragon stopped working, so I think this is a version problem.

The question is, how can I update this Paragon software for macOS 10.12? Do I need to buy a new version of this app???

Samsung's services files do not have a serial number, only some Windows apps and Macintosh NTFS Paragon driver (Paragon 11.3).

Comment: You'd do better directing this question at Paragon. They don't seem to show compatibility information for old versions of their software (that I could find). [They do provide information on how to update](https://www.paragon-software.com/support/update/update.html). I would guess that you would at the very least have to upgrade from 11 to 15 if it's possible. — Paragon NTFS is not however  the only way to handle this situation. The HDD could be formatted for mac. This way you don't need any software (on mac). You could also use free apps, like [Fuse](https://osxfuse.github.io/).

Comment: You question is incomplete! Please add the maker of the HDD! Samsung appears unexpectedly (and somehow unrelated) in your question, so I assume it's an old Samsung drive. Seagate bought Samsung's hard drive division in ~2011. Seagate also provides a free Paragon NTFS driver which only works with Seagate drives. You should download this one and test if the Samsung drive is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need to buy a new version of this ( paragon 15 ).

Comment: that very sad : (

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

You can also contact Samsung/Seagate, maybe they have an updated version of OEM NTFS for Mac for you.